# Windows can't communicate with the device or resource (primary DNS server) Win 8.1

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

I know this has been before, but I tried every single solution I have found and nothing works. Problem is I have Wifi and Ethernet connection. I was working with Wifi until recently. wifi is now awful, slow and disconnects often, and I need fast and reliable connection so I tried to switch to cable internet. Result is the error in the title. I tried every single solution I have found, updated drver, changed adapter settings, tried public dns, cleared dns cache with ipconfig four commands. restarted computer (well, that too), tried every setting under the sky and nothing worked. I got internet for like couple of hours than lost it and that was it. I am losing it because I can't work and this is driving me crazy. Also, I am in group, and we use same provider and same routers and no one else has the problem. So it's something local on my computer. Routers for others are working fine.

Status of the network is always "Limited".

Comment: Your question doesn't contain nearly enough specifics for anyone to offer a logical answer -- eg. specific commands used, results of IPCONFIG etc.  But off the top of my head, experience says the 2 most-likely issues are either a bad network cable or a mis-configured adapter, most likely the subnet mask.  Again, that's a mere guess and someone could venture a more concrete  resolution if you had included the specifics.